# Showing progress value from a list of tasks through ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

My title may make my question sound confusing, but it is not.

I have a list of tasks to do and a `ProgressBar`. When I loop through the list of tasks, I want to display the progress through a `ProgressBar`:

```
        double percentage;
        for(int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
        {
            percentage = (double)i + 1 / (double)tasks.Count;
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round(percentage * 100);
            });
            // Do tasks here...
        }
```

So if I have say, 20 tasks I want `progressBar1` to have the value of 5 `((1 / 20) * 100)`, then when it loops through again it has the value of 10, 15 and so on. The method that I am using right now does not work properly, on the first task `progressBar1` has a value of 0, then when it loops through again it has the value of 100. Is there a way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you updating the progress bar on the main thread? Looks like you're doing it inside of a worker method `//Do tasks here...` but i can't really tell

Comment: @Duane, he is updating the progress bar on the main UI thread, notice the `this.Invoke` call.

Comment: @Duane I am doing them on a worker thread because the tasks may take some time and I want the UI to show the progress of all the tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++)
{
    double percentage = (double)(i + 1) / (double)tasks.Count;
    Action<double> update = p => 
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round(p * 100);
    };
    this.Invoke(update, percentage);
    // Do tasks here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should essentially work, however I'd guess your UI just isn't able to update in time (i.e. there's no context switch happening and you return control only once you're done). I don't have that much experience involving C#, multithreading and UI coding, so I might be a bit off here.

What I'd try to do here is sleeping a moment (even essentially 0 seconds should do the trick) once you start doing your tasks within the tasks thread.

A bit off-topic: I'd like to mention that you're overcomplicating it a bit. Just set the maximum value of your progress bar to the number of tasks, then increase it's value 1 by 1, which removes quite a bit of obsolete math within that loop.

Edit: Yeah, just noticed Darin's answer and he's right: You're missing brackets as well, causing your percentage calculation going wrong.

But keep in mind that doing it that way might cause your total percentage to be slightly off due to precision errors (won't matter a lot depending on number of tasks; but you might not be able to hit exactly 100%).